# Meteor not loading <filename>.app-test[s].js files in --full-app test mode

Tags: meteor, mocha.js

I am using Meteor 1.3.2.4 with [practicalmeteor:mocha](https://github.com/practicalmeteor/meteor-mocha/) to run my unit and integration tests. Testing works as expected in normal test mode with both server and client-side test reporting to the browser as expected. My issue is that when I invoke `meteor test` with the `--full-app` parameter none of the full app test suites are loaded. I have tried naming them with all variations of `<filename>.app-[test|spec]s?.js` to no avail. The test files all live within the `/imports` directory.

Regardless of what I do the report always shows zero tests run on client and server. Adding `console.log` in the test file also yields nothing so it's pretty clear the file is not being loaded. I created a test file within the `/server` directory and it reported the test as run so it's definitely an issue with Meteor loading the specially named files as it's supposed to. Any ideas? I am stumped.

Comment: Looks like [this bug](https://github.com/meteor/meteor/issues/6901).

Comment: Thanks @MasterAM, that is the exact issue.

Comment: Posted as an answer so it could be marked as solved.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a [known issue](https://github.com/meteor/meteor/issues/6901) introduced in v1.3.2.

Either downgrade to v1.3.1 or use v1.3.3 (currently beta, will be released soon) or higher.

Answer (score 0):

Have you, per chance, put the files inside a folder called 'tests'. If so, they won't be run:

*The Meteor build tool and the meteor test command ignore any files located in any tests/ directory. This allows you to put tests in this directory that you can run using a test runner outside of Meteor’s built-in test tools and still not have those files loaded in your application. See Meteor’s default file load order rules.*